# Access Tabulator a table created previously using Angular

Tags: angular, tabulator

I am use Angular 8 and have created a Tabulator table, with the id of 'ex-table-div'

From another Angular component I want to be able to trigger the 'download' method on the tabulator table.

I can get the element using getElementById but this just gets a standard HTML element. Is there any way to get the actual tabulator object or cast the HTML object to the tabulator object ?

Answer (score 0):

YOu don't need to get html but JS constructor object.

```
this.table = new Tabulator("#example-table", {
    height:"311px",
    columns:[
        {title:"Name", field:"name", width:200},
        {title:"Progress", field:"progress", width:100, sorter:"number"},
        {title:"Gender", field:"gender"},
        {title:"Rating", field:"rating", width:80},
        {title:"Favourite Color", field:"col"},
        {title:"Date Of Birth", field:"dob", align:"center", sorter:"date"},
        {title:"Driver", field:"car", align:"center", formatter:"tickCross"},
    ],
});
this.table.download("csv", "data.csv");
```